# Node Js gm, Resize and overlap

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, gm

I want to insert an image(img1) into another(img2) but before inserting, img1 must be resized based on img2 dimensions.
how can I achieve this with [nodeJs gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) ?
I'm using imageMagic.

Comment: Load both images, get the dimensions of image2, resize image1 accordingly then composite it on top of image2 and save.

Comment: Is there any way that no need for saving resized version of image1? Becuse there are some other steps and I want these steps to be done on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak `node`, but here is how you might do it at the command-line. I'll use these two images, both the same size at 200x100.

[image]
[image]

```
convert red.png \( gradient.png -resize 40% \) -gravity southeast -composite result.png
```

That gives this result:

[image]

To translate that into `node`, you need to look at Eric's (@emcconville) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31725668/2836621). I don't believe `GraphicsMagick` supports the parentheses syntax, so I guess you will need to use the more sophisticated `ImageMagick`.

Comment: Thanks @Mark,+1 for your answer , but I was looking for a solution for Node gm.

Comment: Another option may be to use **gm**'s `batch` command like I demonstrate in the second part of the answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34123532/2836621

Answer (score 0):

I just found solution, and answered my own question here: [Resize and compose two or more images using gm in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613515/resize-and-compose-two-or-more-images-using-gm-in-nodejs/40614257#40614257), but here I post for your convenience:

```
gm()
.in('-geometry', '+0+0')
.in('./img/img1.png')
.in('-geometry', '300x300+100+200')
.in('./img/img2.png')
.flatten()
.write('resultGM.png', function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample app with images in working form?